# ImageMagick montage: Resizing only one input image

Tags: imagemagick

I am currently using the following to combine several (e.g. two) images:

`montage a.png b.png -geometry +5+5 -tile 2x1 out.png`

I can resize the first image to 200% before the images are combined:

`montage a.png -resize 200% b.png -geometry +5+5 -tile 2x1 out.png`

However, the following resizes both images:

`montage a.png b.png -resize 200% -geometry +5+5 -tile 2x1 out.png`

Is there a way within this single command to just resize b.png to 200% before the combination takes place?

Comment: I am trying to understand how this is supposed to look... what sizes are your 2 input images please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try resizing during image read with modifier added in square brackets:

`montage a.png b.png"[200%]" -geometry +5+5 -tile x1 out.png`

details: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#read

it is also worth mentioning that you can also crop image while reading

Answer (score 4):

You can use parentheses to apply operations selectively, like this:

```
montage blue.png \( red.png -resize 200% \) -geometry +5+5 -tile 2x1 out.png
```

You may, or may not, need the slashes in front to escape them depending on your shell/environment.

Here is how it looks:

```
convert -size 30x30! xc:red red.png
convert -size 30x30! xc:blue blue.png
```

and your original command:

```
montage blue.png red.png -geometry +5+5 -tile 2x1 out.png
```

[image]

but with selective enlargement as follows:

```
montage blue.png \( red.png -resize 200% \) -geometry +5+5 -tile 2x1 out.png
```

[image]

Very French, I feel :-)

Comment: Awesome, the use of parentheses to apply operations selectively is what I was looking for for a while !

Comment: Great! Glad to be of assistance. Questions are free, so ask away if you have any more.